# SSIS update oracle table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have a SSIS package that performs an update to a Oracle table. I'm using a Data Flow task with a SQL Server OLE DB Source and a OLEDB Command to execute the update.

[image: Dataflow Task]

The update command being executed is:

```
UPDATE NB_STG_APROV_WEB 
SET stock_comm = ? 
WHERE sku = ? AND data_info = trunc(sysdate - 1)
```

Both parameters are mapped. The package executes with success but the table is not updated. Any ideas why?

Comment: If an update succeeds but the table is not updated, it would typically mean that 1) no rows were selected for update by the WHERE clause, 2) the value is being "updated" to whatever it was before, 3) you haven't committed your transaction and are checking from a different session, or 4) you're updating one table/database and accidentally checking a different table/database by mistake. Can you check for those possibilities easily? Did you definitely finish the data flow task to commit the transaction? Does a SELECT with your criteria bring back the rows you expect?

Comment: Answers: 1) rows are being selected. 2) original values are "nulls", new ones not. 3) Added the commit to the command, same result. 4) how can I check that? i'm not used to work with Oracle.

Comment: Read somewhere that it is not possible to update Oracle tables using SQL Commands in Data Flow Tasks... is it true? It's out of the question to create stagging tables on the Oracle Database.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine. SQL Server source, OLEDB Command for an Oracle connection with `UPDATE test SET val = ? WHERE id = 1` set as the SqlCommand, mapped a variable from the source to the external parameter, ran it, saw the update in the database by querying in SQLDeveloper. So it's definitely possible. (On the other hand, it's a shame you can't create staging tables; they're often a cleaner way of doing this if you're updating many rows.)

Comment: @MattGibson is that your full update command? shouldn't it be necessary to issue a commit statement? my full command is `BEGIN
UPDATE NB_STG_APROV_WEB 
SET stock_comm = ? 
WHERE sku = ? AND data_info = trunc(sysdate - 1);
COMMIT;
END;`

Comment: Nope; I have no BEGIN, END or COMMIT -- SSIS should commit the transaction at the end of the processing, and that appears to work fine for me. (I've never had much luck with doing anything more complex than a single command when putting Oracle statements into SSIS...)

Comment: Personally i avoid doing SQL Command type destinations for updates - its REALLY slow, and also you are trusting something to happen without any way of auditing.  I normally write changes to a change table (just a copy of the destination) and then execute a merge.  Its so much more efficient, and you can review the "change" table afterwards to see what should have happened (useful to email audit trails if needed aswell)